# way to rewrite LDAP field name before getting to client?

Tags: ldap

We have access to an LDAP server that has a field we need the information from.  Its structure cannot be changed.  We have a client application that requires the field to a certain name.  How can we change the field name to match what we need before it gets to the application?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to deploy a device that can do transformations on attribute names, for example, a [Directory Proxy Server](https://www.unboundid.com/resources/product-descriptions/files/directory-proxy-server.pdf) or Synchronization Server. Alternatively, if your directory server supports plugins, one could write such a plugin to do the job.